# What Kind of Service Do I Need to Use for Sending User-to-User Push Notifications on iOS

Tags: mbaas

I need a little help with understanding what to look for when selecting a service to use for allowing my application's users to create accounts and send push notifications to each other. I do not have any backend service experience, except for with Parse, and I don't understand some of the functionality requirements.

I want users to be able to register an account and add other users. Then, I would like the users to be able to select specific users from their "friends" list in order to send a push notification to each selected user for a meeting. However, I honestly don't even know where to start.

It seems that many of the services that I have looked at are set up for sending targeted push notifications to groups of users from a dashboard (seemingly for marketing and other purposes).

I am completely new to servers and backends, except for a little activity with Parse, so can anyone recommend a direction for me to take for integrating such functionality in an iOS application that I am working on?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [mbaas](https://www.built.io/products/backend/overview) providers like [built.io backend](https://www.built.io/products/backend/overview), It provides push notification functionality on object creation event, and a set of ACL can be specified on these objects. This will act as a filter criteria as to who are the allowed to receive this push notification.

You can refer to their docs here https://docs.built.io